# Python2.7 default float precision

Tags: python

Does anyone know what is Python's default float precision value? Couldn't find anything via Google!

Comment: `python2 -c "import sys; print(sys.float_info)"`

Comment: First hit on google for 'python default float precision` gives this, where it states 53 bits: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @roelofs actually, you will see that the underlying `float` representation is dependent on your *platform*, although as stated in the link, "almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”." So basically, they are doubles.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am given this but I don't know if it is equivalent to `float64` or `float32`: `sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - OP asked for default, which I took to (also) mean default for typical systems.  I guess that may have been a bad assumption.

Comment: @roelofs no, I'm probably just being pedantic.

Comment: @Medo well, if the mantissa is already using 53 bits, i.e. `mant_dig=53`, then surely it cannot be `float32`, so that strongly suggests its `float64`. As stated already, pretty much on all modern computers you will have float64, or rather, "IEEE-754 double-precision"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
print sys.float_info
```

Running this will give you something like this..

```
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

To know more about the values follow this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) for official python docs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Python 2 documentation:

> On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision
>   available for a Python float, so the value stored internally when you
>   enter the decimal number 0.1 is the binary fraction
>
> `0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010`
>
> which is close to, but not exactly equal to, 1/10.